# Swift4- Is there any way to build an chatting app without fire base

Tags: ios, xcode, chat, swift4

Swift4- Is there any way to build an chatting app with normal api with web service with no fire base ?!! Any help any tutorial

Comment: This question is to broad and not about a specific coding issue. Learn how to ask a question properly here on SO please.

Comment: Sorry ill do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are so many ways of building chatting app. You have to choose backend or technology which helps you to maintain continuous connectivity between your app and your backend server which stores your chat data.

You can use https://socket.io, https://nodejs.org/en or SignalR, etc. based on which suits to your backend or requirements.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you i was meat it before but i was dont know what it do

Comment: You can refer https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ link for basic tutorial.